# LibGDX: GWT Module com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d not found in project sources or resources

Tags: java, maven, gwt, libgdx

I've been trying to export my libGDX game using the gwt backend, but have run into the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0:compile (default) on project Game-html: GWT Module com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d not found in project sources or resources. -> [Help 1]
```

I did add to my gwt.xml to inherit the name, and I did add box2d as a dependency, but I still get the error. My gwt.xml looks like this:

```
<module rename-to='Game'>
    <inherits name='com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gdx_backends_gwt' />
    <inherits name='package.Game' />
    <inherits name='com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.box2d-gwt' />

    <source path='core'/>
    <source path='html'/>

    <public path="resources" />

    <entry-point class='package.GameHtml'/>
    <set-configuration-property name="gdx.assetpath" value="assets" />
    <set-configuration-property name='gdx.assetoutputpath' value='html/target/webapp' />
</module>
```

and here are my box2d dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
    <artifactId>gdx-box2d-gwt</artifactId>
    <version>${gdx.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.badlogicgames.gdx</groupId>
    <artifactId>gdx-box2d-gwt</artifactId>
    <version>${gdx.version}</version>
    <classifier>sources</classifier>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Box2D being made into an extension only happened recently, so I couldn't find any good examples of it that also use maven, so I might have just used the wrong dependencies, but I don't know. Anybody know what I did wrong?

EDIT: Project structure, as requested

```
Project/
|-- assets
|
|-- core
|  |-- src
|    |-- main
|      |-- java
|        |-- package
|  |-- pom.xml
|
|-- html
|  |-- src
|    |-- main
|      |-- java
|        |-- package
|          |-- Project.gwt.xml
|  |-- war
|    |-- WEB-INF
|      |-- web.xml
|    |-- index.html
|  |-- pom.xml
|
|-- pom.xml
```

Comment: Always follow [Standard Directory and Package Layout](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideDirectoriesPackageConventions). Please share your project structure.

Comment: A more link about [Project Structure](http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.doc.DeveloperGuide.Fundamentals.ProjectStructure.html)

Comment: I added my project structure. I'm not sure how useful the standard directory and package layout is, however, as I'm using maven and am using the libgdx-gwt-backend, as opposed to native gwt.